# Error al consultar base de datos en un Middleware con Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

Tengo un Middleware en mi proyecto que consulta el status (activo = 1 o inactivo=0) de un usuario con el ID de usuario y si este esta inactivo devuelve una vista que se llama transacciones, cuando ejecuto el código me sale el error:

> Object of class Illuminate\Support\Collection could not be converted
>   to int

supongo que es porque el status esta en numero entero, como le hago para que lo lea, dejo el código de mi Middleware

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;

use Closure;
use DB;
use Auth;

class StatusActivo
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */

  public function handle($request, Closure $next)
   {
   $id = Auth::id();
   $status = DB::table('users')->where('status',$id)->get();
   if($status == 1){ // si es null, es porque no existe y retornamos la vista
     return redirect()->route('transacciones');
   }
   //caso contrario seguimos con petición
   return $next($request);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema radica en esta linea, ya que esta retorna una colección *(Collection)* y no podrá validar si es `==1` en el `if` , además no tendría sentido para la validación que desea.

```
$status = DB::table('users')->where('status',$id)->get(); // return collection
```

Otro problema es que para obtener el usuario, no es correcto utilizar el Fascade `Auth`, el usuario está disponible en la variable `$request`.

```
$id = $request->user()->id; // id usuario logueado
```

La consulta debería ser, seleccionar el usuario con el id del usuario Logueado, y además que su estado sea activo.

Pero ya no es necesario realizar una nueva consulta a la base de datos.

Como se tiene el usuario en la sesión, podría validarse a partir de esto y verificar su estado y así saber que acción realizar.

```
function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if($request->user()->status == 0){ //inactivo
        return redirect()->route('transacciones');
    }
    //caso contrario seguimos con petición - activo
    return $next($request);

}
```

Comment: Gracias! tienes toda la razon, quiza eran las altas horas en que lo hice